# What does -z and -o commands mean in Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

I have a script.sh shell script where in I come across the following line in a function :

```
if [ -z "$CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED" -o "$CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED" = "false" ]; 

then
        ....

else
        ....

fi
```

I want to know what the **-z** and **-o** in the If statements means

Thanks

Comment: Google "man test"...seriously, it'll give you what you need

Comment: `[` is actually a command here, and it’s an alias for `test`. Look at `man test`.

Comment: Your code is checking to see if `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED` empty or if it is set to `false`.   See this post on Unix & Linux site to understand `[ ]` and other variants: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/201820)

Comment: `help test | grep -- -z`

Comment: got it Thanks a lot !

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite basic actually:
-z means test for empty string (zero length)
-o is a OR operation

If you want to do scripting in bash I recommend you go through "Bash Beginners Guide". It will cover the necessary basics, and does not take much time.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Comment: TLDP isn't a great source for Bash - it is full of inaccuracies.

Comment: @codeforester do you have another recommendation for beginners? Should be quick to learn and get you started. There are of course many advanced and comprehensive ones.